# Runtime error on Firefox (automated testing)

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm using watir-webdriver for testing.

I seem to be having a rather odd issue where one of my tests passes with google chrome but fails on firefox, I just get a runtime error, doesn't seem to be any more information than that.

-> Error: An error has occured (RuntimeError)

The function is simply just selecting two options from two input lists

code

```
def selectSprint(team, sprint)
    @browser.div(:id, "sprintTitle").click  #Navigate to the Team/Sprint drop down boxes
    @browser.div(:id, "teamTitle").wait_until_present
    @browser.div(:id, "teamTitle").select_list(:id, "Select").select("#{team}")  
    @browser.div(:id, "sprintTitle").wait_until_present  #Move to Sprint drop down box  
    @browser.div(:id, "sprintTitle").select_list(:id, "Select").select("#{sprint}")     
    $log.debug("Team and sprint successfully selected")
    @browser.div(:id => "mainBoard").wait_until_present #checks if page has updated
    rescue => e
    puts "Error: #{e}"
    return true
    $log.info("Method "+"#{__method__}"+" has finished ")
    return true
  end
```

Comment: Doing `puts e` does not give you the full exception. Try adding `puts e.backtrace` to your rescue, which will output the stacktrace portion of the exception. From that, it might make it easier to debug the issue.

Comment: Or even easier, do not rescue the error, so all the details will be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The waiting and existence methods don't work with Firefox 17, so you'll have to revert to Firefox 16 for the time being. I've heard that an update to watir-webdriver is being released next week to resolve the issues with Firefox 17.

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense, thank you. I'll just keep a close eye on the watir blog for now.

Answer (score 0):

If your script is running successfully in one browser then it should run in all, it might be happening because of Firefox browser version you are using, even I had such kind of issue and then I updated the browser and after that issue got resolved.

Update your Firefox and then try again to run your test.

Comment: I've only had the issue with firefox since the latest release!

Comment: Then might be your latest Firefox is not updated properly, for debugging purpose you can try running your script with some older version of Firefox.